# kinetic.js stage.getDragLayer method

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to learn some kinetic.js. I heve some problem with following example:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-modify-curves-with-anchor-points-using-kineticjs/

What does this part actually do:

```
stage.getDragLayer().beforeDraw(function() {
      drawCurves(curveLayer.getCanvas(), layer.quad, layer.bezier);
      updateDottedLines(layer);
    });
```

I mean getDragLayer() method and beforeDraw() method.

Comment: kinetic js uses a temporary drag layer which it places nodes (shapes) in when you drag so that the drawing is done faster. so getDragLayer references the temporary drag layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KineticJS builds a specialized layer that handles drag/drops.

**getDragLayer()** gets a reference to this layer.

**beforeDraw()** allows a function to be executed before any drawing related to the drag/drop are started.  In this case, drawCurves() and updateDottedLines() are called--these 2 functions are defined in the demo you're learning.